# Multiple Checkboxes error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple checkboxes in my program but it's not working. I am giving my code below. please check and let me know where I am doing wrong. I am a beginner in angularjs.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li class="col s6 m2" data-ng-repeat="item in amenities.general_amenities track by item.id">
            <input type="checkbox"ng-model="checkboxModel.value" checked>
            <label for="general_amenities">
                <span data-ng-bind="item.amenities"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controller Code:

```
.controller(
    'appCtrl',
    ["$scope", '$connectivityModel',
    function ($scope, $cm) {
        angular.extend($scope, {
            common: [],
            $scope : checkboxModel = {
                value : true,
            },
```

Continuation to same problem i am adding a snapshot and code in which I want to create similar row with same text on click of add button.

[image]

**HTML:**

```
                     <div class="row">

                    <div class="input-field col s10 m6">
                        <input id="near_metro" type="text">
                        <label for="near_metro" class="">Near Metro Station</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s2 m2">
                        <button class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit"
                                name="action" data-ng-submit="addNew(row in connectivity)" value="<%row.value%>"><%row.text%>>
                            <i class="material-icons right">add</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m4">
                        <input id="road" type="text">
                        <label for="road" class="">Road</label>
                    </div>


                </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What isn't working exactly, can you tell a little more about the problem?

Comment: You also might want to add a snippet to your post. This way we can see a (non) working version of your code. Allowing us to quickly respond to the problem.

Comment: For starters, your HTML is missing a space here ```type="checkbox"ng-model="checkboxModel.value"``` after the "checkbox"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.checkboxs = [
         { name: "Red", id: 0, isChecked: true }, 
         { name: "Blue", id: 1, isChecked: false }, 
         { name: "Green", id: 2, isChecked: true },
         { name: "Yellow", id: 3, isChecked: true }, 
         { name: "Orange", id: 4, isChecked: false }, 
         { name: "Purple", id: 5, isChecked: true }
      ];
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="check in checkboxs">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="check.isChecked" /> {{check.name}} 
    </label>
  </body>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope){
       $scope.checkboxs = {checkbox1: true, checkbox2: false};
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="(check,enabled) in checkboxs">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxs[check]" /> {{check}} 
    </label>
  </body>

</html>
```

Hope it works for you.